# Bot server returned HTTP 5xx when trying to connect to azure SQL

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, botframework

I was trying to record the bot and user's activities with Azure SQL following this [tutorial](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/13/Implementing-A-SQL-Server-Database-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework). However, the bot returned HTTP 5xx error in the Azure Web app dashboard.

The DB worked locally but not remotely on Azure SQL. I have added all IP of the Web App to the SQL firewall and copied the connectionString of Azure SQL to the publish option. When I tested it using skype the bot did not respond and showed a 5xx server error in the dashboard.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="BotDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BotData.csdl|res://*/Models.BotData.ssdl|res://*/Models.BotData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\BotData.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
<parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
 </defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Is there something wrong with my web.config which prevented the bot server to send activity to the Azure SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Examining your programming code it references LocalDB everywhere. It is not targeting SQL Azure Database.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Alberto: your connection string is incorrectly pointing to a local database. Please try changing it to something like:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BotDataEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=[YourDatabaseServerName];Initial Catalog=[YourDatabaseName];Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[YourDatabaseUserId];Password=[YourDatabaseUserPassword];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
  </connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
<parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
 </defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Note:
The Bot Framework team also has a blog post that walks through saving activities in Azure Sql that might be helpful for you: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/05/saving-bot-actions-on-azure-sql-server/